# How to boot ISO from RHEL 8 VM?

Tags: rhel, boot, iso

I need to boot from a RHEL 8 ISO on a VM. How do I do that? All the instructions I'm finding on the web start from the point where you've already booted from the ISO.

Comment: It depends on the virtualization software you're using but generally you add the ISO and boot from it, there's not a lot more that can be said without knowing specifics. Consider [edit]ing the question.

Comment: What is your VM?

Comment: You download the ISO, create a new VM, attach this ISO to it, turn it on. I feel like you don't actually have the ISO and that's your real issue: https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/download

Comment: @BlockchainOffice It's Hyper-V

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I need to use the troubleshooting feature on an existing VM. If I create a new VM how is it going to troubleshoot the problem VM? (I have the ISO already.)

Comment: I do not understand the question, you wanted to know how to boot an iso in a vm or not and ArtemS.Tashkinov told you. But now there is an other problem?

Comment: After you start the vm and you follow the boot process you can't select troubleshooting options or other options provided by rhel 8 ?

Comment: *"how is it going to troubleshoot the problem VM"* you're leaving out crucial details. Please edit your question and specify exactly what you need. This is a help website, not "guess what my issue is and help me" website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the VM configuration includes a virtual CD/DVD drive; stop the VM for reconfiguration if necessary. Then tell the virtual drive to use the .ISO file as a virtual disc. Then change the VM's boot order settings to boot first from CD/DVD, and boot the VM.

The exact details will depend on the virtualization software: for example, on some versions of VMware you might have to go into the VM's "BIOS settings" to change the boot order.

If you need specific instructions on how to achieve this in Hyper-V, ask in [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/) instead.